# Error on reading json file using JSON Simple Library

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read the following `JSON` file in java.

Here is my **JSON** File

```
 {
      "names": [
        {
          "no": 1,
          "name": "John"
        },
        {
          "no": 2,
          "name": "Paul"
        }
        ],
      "new_names": [
        {
          "no": 11,
          "name": "John"
        },
        {
          "no": 12,
          "name": "Paul"
        }
        ]
     }
```

Java Code:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;


public class ReadFile {


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    "D://data.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;


            JSONArray nameList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("names");


            System.out.println("\nnames:");
            Iterator<String> iterator = nameList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print **names** array, but I am getting following **error**:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String  at ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is this line that is causing the problem:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = nameList.iterator();
```

Try using the following instead:

```
arrLength = nameList.Length()
for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; ++i) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = nameList.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(jsonObj)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JSonArray `nameList` has has JSONObjects inside, not the strings,

You should do replace your `String` with `JSONObject` as mentioned in Exception trace

```
 Iterator<JSONObject > iterator = nameList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                 JSONObject jsonObjct= iterator.next()
                System.out.println(jsonObjct.getInt("no"));
                System.out.println(jsonObjct.getString("name"));
            }
```

Comment: @Thanos Which library are you using for your json ?  can please comment import of your JSON object or JSonArray, because I don't find iterator in org.json library for JSonArray

Comment: I guess Iterator wont work on JSON Array, I did it using for loop!

Comment: @Thanos Yes there is not iterator available for JSonArray.

Answer (score 1):

Iteratoring from JsonObject..

So you should change below:

```
 Iterator<String> iterator = nameList.iterator();
```

to following:

```
 Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = nameList.iterator();
```

And iterate it using for loop, Iterator won't work for JSONArray.